# Axios not loading data to vue

Tags: vue.js, axios, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am trying to load cytoscape graph using vue and axios. Anyway cant configure cytoscape so I tried first with axios and vue only. There is still problem with scope, but I can't figure where? What should I change? How to properly set vue and axios.

**EDIT**

So after setting this.nodes i would like to draw a grapg in cytoscape.js , but I always get errors:

-The style property `text-outline-color:` is invalid

-Do not assign mappings to elements without corresponding data (e.g. ele `6b899f09-359e-424d-9461-d71c8c3fcd3b` for property `text-outline-color` with data field `faveColor`); try a `[faveColor]` selector to limit scope to elements with `faveColor` defined

-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'mapping' of null

I believe it is array problem, but I can't figure out how to set array properly so this can work.

Here is code:

```
draw: function(){

    this.cy = cytoscape({
            container: document.getElementById('cy'),
              layout: {
                name: this.main_layout,
                padding: 10
              },
              style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
                .selector('node')
                  .css({
                    'shape': 'data(faveShape)',
                    'width': 'mapData(weight, 40, 80, 20, 60)',
                    'content': 'data(name)',
                    'text-valign': 'center',
                    'text-outline-width': 2,
                    'text-outline-color': 'data(faveColor)',
                    'background-color': 'data(faveColor)',
                    'color': '#fff'
                  })
                .selector(':selected')
                  .css({
                    'border-width': 3,
                    'border-color': '#333'
                  })
                .selector('edge')
                  .css({
                    'curve-style': 'bezier',
                    'opacity': 0.666,
                    'width': 'mapData(strength, 70, 100, 2, 6)',
                    'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
                    'source-arrow-shape': 'circle',
                    'line-color': 'data(faveColor)',
                    'source-arrow-color': 'data(faveColor)',
                    'target-arrow-color': 'data(faveColor)'
                  })
                .selector('edge.questionable')
                  .css({
                    'line-style': 'dotted',
                    'target-arrow-shape': 'diamond'
                  })
                .selector('.faded')
                  .css({
                    'opacity': 0.25,
                    'text-opacity': 0
                  }),
              elements: {
                nodes: this.nodes

              },

              ready: function(){
                window.cy = this;
              }
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `response.data` is an array or object ans `vm.projekt` with `null` there is no vue-getter registred. So please try to do

`Vue.set(vm, 'projekt', response.data)` there is also a $set in every vue instance (this)

instead of

`vm.projekt = response.data`

In general i would advise you to push ajax-datas into reactive arrays, that works very well.

Comment: If I do it this way, in a console I still get null. What's wrong? Here is jsbin [link] https://jsbin.com/piwusuyici/edit?js  I am using npm.

Comment: The jsbin doesn't works. the url your trying to get is propably wrong. You don't have a scoping problem.

Comment: It was just code. But why I am then still getting null in console.log(this.projekt) ?

Comment: `this.to();`  // ajax get started but fn will return before .then is executed
`console.log(this.projekt);`   // this.project is null because .then is triggered after the console prints the log

Comment: That was actually it. There is also new question about array. I posted code and explanation in answer.

Comment: Then you should mark it as answer and open a new question instead of overriding the old question text.